# The same Source and Destination address and ports

Tags: tcp, ip

I am learning how the IP and TCP headers work. The following is my question:

**Can a source address and destination address in an IP header be the same? or doesnt it make any sense?**

[image]

**Similarly, can a source and destination port be the same within a TCP header?**

[image]

I tried searching google but I didnt find anything specific to my question, but rather how the protocols work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, source and destination IP address can be the same. That simply represents a connection between client and server (or 2 peers) on the same host.

Source and destination port can also be the same. If that happens, it would usually happen by coincidence.

But source and destination IP address being the same ***and*** source and destination port being the same? That doesn't make sense. That would represent a TCP connection connected to itself. Even if you wanted to do it (a kind of loopback connection), the protocol wouldn't be able to distinguish packets in one direction from packets in the other direction.

Comment: I don't see why the protocol needs to distinguish packets in one direction from packets in the other direction. Packets that are received are from the peer, whoever he is.

Comment: @EJP TCP maintains several different parameters that are different for each direction of a stream: the sequence number, the cwnd, etc... packets in one direction would match the stream in the other direction (because the protocol, source and destination IP address, and source and destination port all match) but the sequence numbers would be wrong.